# Erro ao fechar uma aba no PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa de teste com o PySimpleGUI, mas basicamente ele pede um usuário, se estiver correto ele abre uma nova aba com a frase: "Sucesso, você entrou na sua conta!", e quando estivesse errado abrisse uma nova aba com uma frase "Senha incorreta. Tente novamente". Estava programando quando precisei interromper o loop `while` quando a pessoa fechasse o programa. Até consegui fazer isso na parte onde pede o usuário, mas quando estava fazendo na parte de senha incorreta, percebi que o python não estava reconhecendo o comando `if click == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:`. Então modifiquei o código para colocar um `input` para ver se ele aparecia, e se ele aparecesse o comando estaria sendo reconhecido. Mas o resultado é o mesmo que o do início:
`You have tried 100 times to read a closed window. You need to add a check for event == WIN_CLOSED`

Aqui está o código (eu sei que não iria fechar com ele, mas só queria que ele reconhecesse o input primeiro)

```
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import sleep
sg.theme("LightGreen4")
x = [
        [sg.Text('Usuário'), sg.Input(key='usuario')],
        [sg.Button('Entrar', key = 'entrar')]
]
janela = sg.Window('lalalala', x)
s = 's'
t = 't'
while s == 's':
    while t == 't':
        click, valores = janela.read()
        if click == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            s = 't'
            click = 'closed'
            break
        elif click == 'entrar':
            if valores['usuario'] == '004848':
                layout = [
                    [sg.Text('Sucesso! Você entrou na sua conta!')]
                ]
                break
            else:
                layout = [
                    [sg.Text('Senha incorreta. Tente novamente.')]
                ]
                break
    if valores['usuario'] == '004848':
        janela3 = sg.Window('sucesso!', layout)
        while True:
            click = janela3.read()
            pass
    elif click == 'closed':
        sg.Window.close(janela)
    else:
        janela3 = sg.Window('senha incorreta', layout)
        while True:
            del(click)
            click = janela3.read()
            if click == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
                input('s')
                sleep(100)
```

Estou utilizando o Windows 10 PRO, 64bit.
Por favor, caso tenha um erro na pergunta escreva nos comentários para eu modificá-la.
Obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente isso: (Obs. não é recomendo usar sleep em uma interface gráfica, isso faz o código esperar um pouco impossibilitando de a interface ser atualizada podendo crashar)

```
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg

def tela1(layout, name_window):
    janela = sg.Window(name_window, layout=layout, finalize=True)
    while True:
        event, values = janela.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break

sg.theme("LightGreen4")
layout = [[sg.Text('Usuário'), sg.Input(key='usuario')],
    [sg.Button('Entrar', key = 'entrar')]]
janela = sg.Window('Window-PySimpleGUI', layout=layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = janela.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'entrar':
        if values['usuario'] == '004848':
            janela.hide()
            layout1 = [[sg.Text('Sucesso! Você entrou na sua conta!')]]
            tela1(layout1, 'sucesso!')
            janela.un_hide()
        else:
            janela.hide()
            layout2 = [[sg.Text('Senha incorreta. Tente novamente.')]]
            tela1(layout2, 'senha incorreta')
            janela.un_hide()
```

Comment: Porque do -2?? Só organizei o código

Comment: Agora eu ainda não posso testar, mas porque você utilizou o janela.hide() e o finalize = True?

Comment: quando vc abre outra janela, é bom "esconder" uma, até pq a outra vai ficar sem resposta(vc não poderá mexer nela).
O finilize é usado para evitar alguns erros que são descritos na documentação: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: obrigado, você resolveu meu problema, mas quando eu quisesse utilizar o sleep, o que eu faria?

Comment: Depende do uso... No PySimpleGui vc pode usar o ```hide``` para esconder a janela e dai pra frente vc pode usar o time.
  Em geral nn se usa muito o time nesses casos, é para um uso bem especifico